# Updating a appsettings.json file from Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, teamcity, configuration-files, msbuild-task

I have a appsettings.json file in my dotnet core project. From Teamcity I need to update the content of the file. File looks something like this

```
{
    "keyofjson":"valuetobeupdated"
}
```

I need to update the text "valuetobeupdated" based on "keyofjson".
In traditional .net projects we had .config file which could be updated using msbuild file based using the target from xmlpeek and xmlpoke tasks. Do we have something same in dotnet core?

Comment: are you looking for msbuild solution? because you can change json file from powershell, groovy, or other build steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In step build use PowerShell script:

```
$filePath = "yourPath"

(GC $filePath).Replace("valuetobeupdated", "keyofjson") | Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: This may not work, the above command will try to find "valuetobeupdated" and if found it will update with "keyofjson". What I am looking at is I need to find the key in that json and then updates it's value to what I mention.

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified that this value is different on a build-by-build basis, if the value you want to change is the same every time you can simply add a build feature and select 'File content replacer' and find and replace 'valuetobeupdated' with the value you want.

If the value is a value that is calculated during the build then you will need to use a build step, e.g. powershell/commandline step to do the said find and replace.

Comment: The file remains same in different configuration, but the value of the json keeps changing. Based on the configuration the code behaves. So I need to update this value based on the key in the json.

Comment: You can configure a build step to locate the value you need then assign that to a teamcity parameter, here is an example I've used before: echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='DB_REVISION' value='$oldRevision']"